# dokku nginx config for meteor

Tags: meteor, nginx, dokku

I'm creating a [deploy guide](https://github.com/thiagoc7/met_deploy) for meteor with dokku, because no one over there worked for me.

It's all working, but I have `websocket connection` error:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://pedidos3.postooliveira.com.br/sockjs/676/4r9udao6/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

It seems like a nginx config [issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942), but I couldn't make it work.

I created a `nginx.conf.template` file, based on [original template from dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/plugins/nginx-vhosts/templates/nginx.conf.template):

```
server {
  listen      [::]:$NGINX_PORT;
  listen      $NGINX_PORT;
  server_name $NOSSL_SERVER_NAME;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/${APP}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/${APP}-error.log;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://$APP;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port \$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start \$msec;
  }
  include $DOKKU_ROOT/$APP/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

What is wrong with this config?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with cloudflare, that does not support websockets on free plans.

The solution is disable the CloudFlare proxy ("grey cloud" the record in CloudFlare DNS Settings).

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that the CDN you are using does not offer support for WebSockets.
Given that this is out of your control, and probably isn't going to change in the near future, I would advise checking out [more advanced solutions that do support WebSockets](https://incapsula.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202579260-Websocket-support-with-Incapsula).

Good luck!